# Как получить роли, которые имеют какие-либо права на объект 1С?

Tags: 1с

В конфигураторе, в объектах есть поле права, в котором сверху написаны все роли, а снизу права, которые у нее есть. Мне нужно получить роли, у которых в правах есть хоть одна галочка (на чтение, изменение и т.д.). Вручную пролистывать каждую роль очень долго, как можно их отфильтровать или с помощью кода достать?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

см. `РегистрСведений.ПраваРолей`